# Template function as parameter of C++ function

Tags: c++, templates

Put it simply, I want a function that return a string value, by calling a template function, which can return `std::string` or `std::vector<std::string>`.  This logic happens a few times within the function, so I created the function `FooCore` to avoid code duplication.  Can I please get some help to get the following code to compile? Thanks.

```
class A
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  T Getter1()
  {
    return T();
  }

  template <typename T>
  T Getter2()
  {
    return T();
  }
};

struct B
{
  template <typename T>
  T Getter1()
  {
    return _a.Getter1();
  }

  template <typename T>
  T Getter2()
  {
    return _a.Getter2();
  }

  B(const A& a, bool scalar, int i) : _a(a), _scalar(scalar), _i(i)
  {}

  template <typename Func>
  std::string FooCore(Func f)
  {
    if (_scalar)
      return f<std::string>();
    else
    {
      auto temp = f<std::vector<std::string>>();
      if (temp.size() > 0)
        return temp[0];
      else
        return "dummy";
    }
  }

  std::string Foo()
  {
    if (_i == 1)
      return FooCore(Getter1);
    else
      return FooCore(Getter2);
  }

  A _a;
  bool _scalar;
  int _i;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b(a, true, 1);
  b.Foo();
}
```

Comment: your example isnt quite clear. Which is the function that either returns `std::string` or a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: `Getter1` should return a `std::string` and `Getter2` should return a `std::vector<std::string>` ? Why are they templates?

Comment: `A::Getter1` and `A:Getter2` Should be the functions that can return `std::string` or `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: You can't pass a template as a function argument.